# terminal curl vs subprocess curl

Tags: curl, python-requests, subprocess

I see a difference in the outputs of curl cmd when I run from the terminal and when I use subprocess.run to execute the same curl from Python script. The cURL from terminal returns the whole output JSON (all pages of an API call), but, the subprocess.run (and requests library) return only the first-page and gives the link for the next page.

The API calls I make are metered...and I can make only 500 calls/day. Given this restriction, I want to use my APIs judiciously. Instead of making repeated calls on 'next' links (using subprocess or requests), I want to see the same behavior of cURL as I see in a terminal (get all the results at once in a big json string).

My APIs need a key...hence, i am unable to provide an example with my key.

Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: You can provide example with fake key

Comment: curl should be the same from a shell (what you call terminal) or python subprocess, assuming it's the same curl program with the same arguments; environment variable(s) _might_ also matter but none spring to mind. Try running both with `-v` to make sure they send exactly the same request. Try running from shell with `curl ... 2>&1 | cat` to mimic the most obvious difference in the subprocess environment and see if has any effect (it shouldn't).